# EditText cursor visible even if the EditText is not editable

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus

I need to introduce data in an `EditText` but i want to use an virtual keyboard, not the android keyboard. If I use `setKeyListener(null)` the cursor is invisible even after using `setCursorVisible(true)`.

Is it possible to make an `EditText` where even if it isn't editable the cursor is visible ?

**EDIT 2 :**
I found an partial method to do that, but it's not working when i'm double taping the EditText.

I made an `setOnClickListner()` and an `setOnLongClickListner()` method for the `EditText`. In this methods I hide the Soft Input from the Window, also i use `setTextIsSelectable(false)`. My only problem is that when I double tap the `EditText` the soft input keyboard shows and I dont know how to hide it, I tried to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` in manifest, but it doesn't work either.

**EDIT :**

Here is the code that I'm using at this moment for my base converter calculator.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText number;
EditText base;
boolean baseB = false;
String numberS = "0";
String baseS = "10";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_main);


    //make the EditText for number and base not editable
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
    number.setKeyListener(null);
    base = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.base);
    base.setKeyListener(null);

    //... more code here (changing fonts for each EditText and changing status bar color

}

// I have a function for each button all are the same

public void onClickBaseChange(View v) {
    if (baseB) {
        baseB = false;
        // i use toasts at this moment to know when i'm on number or base field
        Toast.makeText(this, "Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        baseB = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Base", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void onClickB0(View v) {
    if (numberS.length() > 0 && !numberS.equals("0") && !baseB) {
        numberS += "0";
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        number.setText(numberS, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        number.setSelection(numberS.length());
    } else {
        if (Integer.valueOf(baseS) >= 1) {
            baseS += "0";
            base = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.base);
            base.setText(baseS, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
    }
}

public void onClickB1(View v) {
    if (numberS.equals("0")) {
        numberS = "1";
    } else {
        numberS += "1";
    }
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
    number.setText(numberS, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    number.requestFocus();
    number.setSelection(numberS.length());
}
```

And the xml looks like this :

```
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"

tools:context="manastur.calculator.MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:textSize="50dp" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondRow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/firstRow"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/b1"
        android:onClick="onClickB1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/b2"
        android:onClick="onClickB2" />

   <!-- from this point on is the same, there are 5 LinearLayouts which
   represents the 5 rows of button of the num pad -->
```

Comment: Do you want like dial pad..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran more like the android calculator app.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to achieve that,

While develop I took reference from native [Dialpad](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/39948dc7e34dc2041b801058dada28fedb80c388/src/com/android/contacts/dialpad/DialpadFragment.java) code

KeypadlessKeypad.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class KeypadlessKeypad extends EditText {

    private static final Method mShowSoftInputOnFocus = getSetShowSoftInputOnFocusMethod(
            EditText.class, "setShowSoftInputOnFocus", boolean.class);

    public static Method getSetShowSoftInputOnFocusMethod(Class<?> cls, String methodName, Class<?>... parametersType) {
        Class<?> sCls = cls.getSuperclass();
        while (sCls != Object.class) {
            try {
                return sCls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parametersType);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // Just super it again
            }
            sCls = sCls.getSuperclass();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Context mContext;


    /**
     * Listener for Copy, Cut and Paste event
     * Currently callback only for Paste event is implemented
     */
    private OnEditTextActionListener mOnEditTextActionListener;

    public KeypadlessKeypad(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public KeypadlessKeypad(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public KeypadlessKeypad(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;

        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
    }


    public final void appendText(CharSequence text) {
        append(text, 0, text.length());
    }

    /***
     * Initialize all the necessary components of TextView.
     */
    private void init() {

        setSingleLine(true);

        synchronized (this) {
            setInputType(getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }

        reflexSetShowSoftInputOnFocus(false); // Workaround.

        // Ensure that cursor is at the end of the input box when initialized. Without this, the
        // cursor may be at index 0 when there is text added via layout XML.
        setSelection(getText().length());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        hideKeyboard();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final boolean ret = super.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Must be done after super.onTouchEvent()
        hideKeyboard();
        return ret;
    }

    private void hideKeyboard() {
        final InputMethodManager imm = ((InputMethodManager) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
        if (imm != null && imm.isActive(this)) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void reflexSetShowSoftInputOnFocus(boolean show) {
        if (mShowSoftInputOnFocus != null) {
            invokeMethod(mShowSoftInputOnFocus, this, show);
        } else {
            // Use fallback method. Not tested.
            hideKeyboard();
        }
    }

    public static Object invokeMethod(Method method, Object receiver, Object... args) {
        try {
            return method.invoke(receiver, args);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int textViewWidth = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        this.setMeasuredDimension(textViewWidth, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before,
                                 int after) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
        boolean consumed = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.paste:
                if (mOnEditTextActionListener != null) {
                    mOnEditTextActionListener.onPaste();
                }
                break;
        }

        return consumed;
    }


    /**
     * Setter method for {@link #mOnEditTextActionListener}
     *
     * @param onEditTextActionListener
     *         Instance of the {@link OnEditTextActionListener}
     */
    public void setOnEditTextActionListener(OnEditTextActionListener onEditTextActionListener) {
        this.mOnEditTextActionListener = onEditTextActionListener;
    }


    private Rect mRect = new Rect();

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

        int[] location = new int[2];
        getLocationOnScreen(location);
        mRect.left = location[0];
        mRect.top = location[1];
        mRect.right = location[0] + getWidth();
        mRect.bottom = location[1] + getHeight();

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !mRect.contains(x, y)) {
            InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED) {
            // Since we're replacing the text every time we add or remove a
            // character, only read the difference. (issue 5337550)
            final int added = event.getAddedCount();
            final int removed = event.getRemovedCount();
            final int length = event.getBeforeText().length();
            if (added > removed) {
                event.setRemovedCount(0);
                event.setAddedCount(1);
                event.setFromIndex(length);
            } else if (removed > added) {
                event.setRemovedCount(1);
                event.setAddedCount(0);
                event.setFromIndex(length - 1);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED) {
            // The parent EditText class lets tts read "edit box" when this View has a focus, which
            // confuses users on app launch (issue 5275935).
            return;
        }
        super.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(event);
    }

    /**
     * Interface to get callback from the Edittext copy, cut and paste event
     * For time being only the Paste Event callback is generated
     */
    public interface OnEditTextActionListener {

        /**
         * If Edittext get paste event then this method will be called
         */
        void onPaste();
    }

}
```

In your xml you can give like this,

```
<[package name].KeypadlessKeypad
        android:id="@+id/dialnumbertv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

And in your fragment you can implement like this,

```
   public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mDialNumbertv = view.findViewById(R.id.dialnumbertv);

        mDialNumbertv.setCursorVisible(false);

        mDialNumbertv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isDigitsEmpty()) {
                    mDialNumbertv.setCursorVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });

        mDialNumbertv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (isDigitsEmpty()) {
                    mDialNumbertv.setCursorVisible(false);
                }
//                updateDeleteButton();
            }
        });

        mDialNumbertv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // Ref https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/39948dc7e34dc2041b801058dada28fedb80c388/src/com/android/contacts/dialpad/DialpadFragment.java
                // Right now EditText does not show the "paste" option when cursor is not visible.
                // To show that, make the cursor visible, and return false, letting the EditText
                // show the option by itself.
                mDialNumbertv.setCursorVisible(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

        mDialNumbertv.setOnEditTextActionListener(
                new KeypadlessKeypad.OnEditTextActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPaste() {
                        // If some content pasted on mDialNumbertv
                        // we need to run some search on Contact and Price

                        String mobileNumber = mDialNumbertv.getText().toString();

                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mobileNumber)) {
                            return;
                        }

//                        updateContactName(mobileNumber);
                    }
                });

    }

    private KeypadlessKeypad mDialNumbertv;

    private boolean isDigitsEmpty() {
        return mDialNumbertv.length() == 0;
    }

    private void setClickedDigit(final String digitToSet) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(digitToSet)) {

            char digit = digitToSet.charAt(0);

            String mobileNumber = mDialNumbertv.getText() + digitToSet;
            mDialNumbertv.getText().insert(mDialNumbertv.getSelectionStart(), digitToSet);

            // If the cursor is at the end of the text we hide it.
            final int length = mDialNumbertv.length();
            if (length == mDialNumbertv.getSelectionStart() && length == mDialNumbertv.getSelectionEnd()) {
                mDialNumbertv.setCursorVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To be honest that is to much for me, i can't understant a lot of that code or even found something that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same behavior which I achieved as follows -

1. Make a custom class that will override 2 methods of AppCompatEditText.

   ```
    class CustomEditText(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatEditText(context, attrs) {
    override fun onCheckIsTextEditor(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun isTextSelectable(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
   }
   ```
2. In the XML file, create EditText using this custom view.

   ```
    <com.ui.custom.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
   ```
3. Now, just add onFocusChangeListener and set editText.setKeyListener = null.

   ```
     binding.etEmail.onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            binding.etEmail.keyListener = null
        }
    }
   ```

You can add the same on onTouch if that is the requirement.

The main issue here is that onCheckIsTextEditor() of View class always returns false, which leads to cursor never blinking or being visible even if setCursorVisible(true) was called in code.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use edittext.setselection(0)

or

maybe you can request focus using requestfocus()

Comment: I already use `setSelection(data.lenght())`. And it seems that `requestFocus()` doesn't work too.

Comment: requestfocus in oncreate

Comment: I use `requestFocus()` in `onCreate`, right under `setKeyListener(null)` and still nothing.

Comment: add some code to the question as well as the layout file containing edittext to get a better understanding.